# Arithmetic overflow when trying to process message block in MD5 algorithm

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, md5

Hi so im making a program in VB.Net which will hopefully output the MD5 hash of a string without using System.Security.Cryptography (not the smartest but i fancied a challenge) using the implementation from here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321
Anyway im getting an Arithmetic overflow when i run my code. Up until this point it has been running rather smoothly with the inputted string being converted to binary, padded correctly etc.
However when i get to stage 4 where i have to process the message block it goes a little strange. Specifically on this function where it returns an Arithmetic overflow on the line labelled:

```
 Function R1(ByRef a As ULong, ByRef b As Integer, ByRef c As Integer, ByRef d As Integer, ByRef splitmessagepart As String, ByRef S As Integer, ByRef i As Integer, ByRef T() As Long)
    'the line below returns the arithmetic overflow
    a = b + ((a + (f(b, c, d)) + splitmessagepart + T(i)) << S)

    Return a
End Function
```

This is function F:

```
 Function f(ByRef X As String, ByRef Y As String, ByRef Z As String)

    Dim endresult As String

    endresult = (X And Y) Or (Not X And Z)

    Return endresult
End Function
```

And then this is the line which calls the function R1:

```
splitmessagepart = splitmessage(0)
    a = R1(a, b, c, d, splitmessagepart, 7, 1, T)
```

Through some debugging i have found that my splitmessagepart variable isnt correctly translated from Binary to decimal in another function but even if i change it so that it is the correct decimal version i still get the overflow. Im assuming this happens on the other 3 functions also which do something similar to this however the program encounters an error on the first line.
I was wondering if i could have a little help figuring out why this is happening? If theres any code needed that i havent put in please ask i really want to get this to work!

Thanks

Comment: I think you should rethink the way you're implementing the algorithm altogether. The `String` keyword should be missing altogether, except for functions such as `ToString` which can be used for debugging / logging. Binary is octets / octet strings, i.e. byte arrays. The input, output and should be on octets, the inner workings on words. Create a special function you can call if you want to look at the intermediate results, but don't use strings within any calculations.

Comment: Note that calculations are not "checked" in VB afaik, so really the exception can only happen when decoding values to `Integer`. I'm not sure if I like the `ByRef` much, probably the ref is larger than the integer in the first place, I don't see the need for it (but I'm not a VB programmer - I presume the usage is identical to other languages).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So for any binary value i should store it in a byte array never as a string? Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the calculation into its parts and check precisely with the watch which operator throws the exception.

More importantly, it looks like you have set the option strict off. This not a good practice unless you absolutely have to. You define the parameters of the function `f` as string, but you pass Integers to it, so they will implicitly converted to strings. Inside `f` you use `and` and `or` which will again implicitly convert your parameters because these operators are not defined on strings. Also you have not defined the type of the output of the function.
More over you have defined `splitmessagepart` as string and you try to use `+` between strings and integers. Are you aware what the result will be.
I advise you to turn the option strict on and check on all these implicit conversions, they are probably not what you expect.

FYI, the doc states that a word is a 32-bit object, so an integer. I doubt there should be a string anywhere in the algorithm.